# For categorical variables generated by SMOTER

Tags: python, machine-learning, regression, smote

I am working on building a predictive model for a regression problem.
And I am suffering from a phenomenon where the model cannot learn well due to the large number of '0's in the target variable.

So, I have arrived at a SMOTER（SMOTE for Regression） that corresponds to an imbalance in the objective variable.

The code is described below.

```
!pip install resreg
!pip install smogn
import resreg
import smogn
import seaborn as sns

X_smoter, y_smoter = resreg.smoter(
X_train, y_train,
relevance=relevance,
k=5,
over="balance",
under=0.33,
random_state=0,
nominal=None)


sns.kdeplot(data=y_train,label="org")
sns.kdeplot(data=y_smoter,label='smoter')
plt.title('Distribution plots of target variables')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

As a result, we succeeded in changing the distribution of the data so that it is not biased toward '0'.

However, the categorical variable gender (e.g. 0 for males and 1 for females) is mixed with a continuous variable such as '0.3'.

Is there any way to extend the data by SMOTER and address the issue of categorical variables becoming continuous variables?